# EXCEL VBA: How to use a variable in a formula for an INDEX function

Tags: vba, excel

I think I'm close but....I need 'LR' to show up as the next row number in a formula. Any ideas?

```
'Get the next row number
LR=ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0.Row

'If LR above is 25...then I need cell D:25 to contain  =INDEX(E25:P25,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((E25:P25<>0),0),0))

ws.Range("D" & LR) = "=INDEX(E[LR]:P[LR],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((E[LR]:P[LR]<>0),0),0))"
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: By the way, if you are not sure what a string will actually output, you can always use `Debug.print "your string goes here"` and check if you get what you want. The result will appear in the *Immediate Window* under your code. If you do not see it, enable it under the *View* tab, or by pressing *Ctrl+G*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ws.Range("D" & LR) = "=INDEX(E" & LR & ":P" & LR & _
                     ",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((E" & LR & ":P" & LR & _
                     "<>0),0),0))"
```

The problem is that you are not getting the **value of** `LR` but **the string "LR"**. If you want to get the value, you have to use the symbol *&*, just as you did in `ws.Range("D" & LR)`.

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks for the Debug.print advice as well.

Comment: You are welcome! I too had issues with strings when I started and Debug.Print was the easiest way I could test my strings. make good use of it!